# How to delete the bloat from Spring Boot app to reduce memory footprint and startup time?

Tags: spring-boot, cloud, microservices, proguard, memory-footprint

Even simple Spring Boot app jar contains lots of dependencies and functionality which never will be used by your app. 
All this stuff:

- should be loaded and it takes its time
- many of these classes should be instantiated, initialized and will consume the memory and resources.

It could be crucial for micro service architecture and cloud native apps where memory footprint could be a price (e.g. https://run.pivotal.io/pricing/) and/or startup time is important.

E.g. the *spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.6.RELEASE.jar* (1.2Mb) contains *couchbase*, *freemaker*, *cassandra* and many others which with 99% probability never be used for your particular project. Or *spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar* (1.2Mb) contains the classes like *KotlinDetector*. Seriously? In core lib? 
I never will use this full of OOP anti-patterns ugly language. Why should I care on it in my app?

Why should I pay for all this useless stuff?

I'm tried to use ProGuard to get rid all unused classes and methods. But it seems no way for Spring Boot, Hibernate etc which are using Reflection API, AOP and even debug information!
ProGuard was not able even to finish with no errors complaining on lack of some classes.

Another idea to use *jlink*, *GraalVM native image* and native build. And I found bunch of articles on that. For my understanding it is impossible to use it for Spring Boot app at this time.

Spring Boot is nice tool to build the apps.

QUESTION: is there a way to get rid all unused stuff from your final Spring Boot jar/war?

Comment: This seems more like a rant than a real question. As a real question it's vague and opinionated--one person's "unused stuff" is another person's essential feature. Further, you haven't explained how you're building your app, so there's no way to provide specific instructions on how to exclude particular dependencies.

Comment: Please reread carefully my question. It is straight forward.
Is there a way to get rid all unused stuff from the final Spring Boot jar or war file.

Unused stuff is anything which is not used and not needed for execution of your app. Like classes, methods in the classes, resources etc. Whatever you can drop from your binary without regression.

E.g. I will be happy if you show me working ProGuard gradle solution which is working well for Spring Boot app. Or whatever which is able significantly reduce the Spring Boot app footprint.

Say run simple restful service within max 10Mb memory.

Answer (score 0):

Please read about [Spring Boot Maven Plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/examples/exclude-dependency.html)
 It explains how you can exclude dependency during packaging,

By default, both the repackage and the run goals will include any provided dependencies that are defined in the project. A Spring Boot project should consider provided dependencies as container dependencies that are required to run the application

> There are two ways one can exclude a dependency from being
>   packaged/used at runtime
>
> 1. Exclude a specific artifact identified by groupId and artifactId (optionally with a classifier if needed)
> 2. Exclude any artifact belonging to a given groupId

**however I doubt if you can remove anything inside any artifact**

```
<plugins>
  ...
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.8.RELEASE</version>
    <configuration>
      <excludes>
        <exclude>
          <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
          <artifactId>bar</artifactId>
        </exclude>
      </excludes>
    </configuration>
    ...
  </plugin>
  ...
</plugins>
```

**Also you can handle it at dependency level using exclusions**

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency
```

Comment: Of course it is the first we can do just run ./gradlew dependencies and check what could be excluded. Another idea to use pure Spring or at least turn on just used Autoconfigurers. You gain little but make dev process complicated.
You won't be able to exclude spring-core-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar and alike which are large and most of its classes are useless for you.

Comment: Yes using pure spring instead of boot will add more complexity than it will solve. but you never know if you end up using any feature of core in future which you are not using . but I think we know not much can be done .